# When compiling a list of MySQL rows to exclude: to Pre-Compile or not to Pre-Compile?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

On one of my PHP sites, I need to offer my Users the ability to select certain rows to exclude from all search results (queries) on the site.

Which way should I go about handling the exclusions, should I:

1) Pre-compile that list of excluded rows whenever the user logs in (or updates it) by querying it, save the list in a Session variable, and then simply add `$query .= " AND userid NOT IN ({$_SESSION['ExclusionList']})"` to every search query on the site,

or

2) Compile it always on-the-fly directly in each query by simply adding  `$query .= " AND userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM Excluded WHERE excludedBy = '$currentUserID')"` to every search query on the site?

Method 1) seems more efficient since I'm only compiling the list once when the user logs in (or whenever they update it), rather than having to essentially compile the list every time any user runs a search query on the site.

What do you suggest and why?

Comment: Always be very careful to properly escape *any* and *all* values inserted into SQL queries to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this would be called "caching" the values and it's not a bad idea provided the lists don't get too huge or your `$_SESSION` could end up being kind of heavy-weight.

Doing a sub-select can be very expensive, especially on large sets of records, so you're usually better off caching it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my belief.  Now, what would you consider "too huge" for a session variable?  Would a list of 500 numbers be "too huge" for example?  At which point does it become "too huge" for the $_SESSION where it becomes more worthwhile to do the sub-select?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, considering you're going to have to load this session in for each and every request, it's somewhat subjective. 4KB of data is generally okay, which might translate to ~580 6-digit numbers including commas. If it's unlikely this list will get that huge, you should be okay. If this is for some kind of ignore system, keep in mind most users will only ignore a few people, but some are real haters and ignore *aggressively*.